# URL codificadas %7B%7B$ -- %7D%7D/%7B%7B$ -- %7D%7D

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Tengo una ruta que envía todos los datos bien al controlador, pero cuando llegan los datos a la URL los datos se convierten en símbolos. Entiendo que `%7B%7B$ dato %7D%7D` es lo mimo que `{{$dato}}`

¿Alguien sabe como evitar esto?

```
    public function code($status, $user){

    return $this -> get('userstatus/{{$status}}/{{$user}}');

}
```

**Resultado:**

```
http://MyRuta/userstatus/%7B%7B$status%7D%7D/%7B%7B$user%7D%7D
```

**Debería ser:**

```
http://MyRuta/userstatus/24/125
```

Cuando hago lo siguiente funciona, pero solo con una variable, si lo intento con los dos no funciona:

```
public function code($status, $user){

return $this -> get('userstatus/.$status');
```

}

**resultado:**

```
http://MyRuta/userstatus/24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareciera como si intentaras usar sintaxis de blade, pero estás en un controlador.

Debería funcionar si haces:

```
return $this->get('userstatus/' . $status . '/' . $user);
```

O también con comillas dobles:

```
return $this->get("userstatus/{$status}/{$user}");
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Mi error era que estaba concatenando mal: return $this->get('userstatus/' . $status  '/' $user); y es como lo escribes tu: return $this->get('userstatus/' . $status . '/' . $user);  Gracias.

Comment: Con gusto, si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: ¡Hecho!. Sabes a que se debe que convierta las { } en esos códigos?

Comment: Se debe a esto: http://php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funcionó lo que encontre en CodeDocu Developer, se remplaza `{}` por `+`

Antes:

```
const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${name}"
```

Después:

```
const response = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/" +name)
```

Comment: Esto tiene toda la pinta de que es JS. La pregunta es acerca de PHP.